# Get index of parent div from child divs

Tags: jquery, indexing, parent

I have a few divs and inside them I have nested divs. I would like to be able to get the index of the parent div my child divs reside in. Ie: If I clicked "post5" I would get the index1 or If I clicked "post4" it would still get index 1.

Html:

```
 <div class="more-content">
   <div class="post">post 1</div>
   <div class="post">post 2</div>
   <div class="post">post 3</div>
 </div>
<div class="more-content">
  <div class="post">post 4</div>
  <div class="post">post 5</div>
  <div class="post">post 6</div>
</div>
 <div class="more-content">
  <div class="post">post 7</div>
  <div class="post">post 8</div>
  <div class="post">post 9</div>
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".post").click(function() {
    alert($(".post").parent.index(this));
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$(".post").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().index(".more-content");
    alert(index);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NDySY/