# javascript get parent div on drag start

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to get the text `Urgent Doing` when I drag the `div class="Card-Container"`. I already get the id correctly (through JS), but I'm not certain how to get the value of a class that is a parent of the Card-Container. I tried [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162206/get-index-of-parent-div-from-child-divs) but couldn't figure out how to get it to bind to the drag_start function properly.

**To see the output try dragging the black title box**

```js
    function drag_start(ev) {
        var cardid = ev.target.id;
        var classtext = $('#'+cardid).parents("div").prev().text();//$(cardid).parents("div").prev().text()
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("elem_id", cardid);
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("div_from_classname", classtext);//Lane-Title-2
        console.log("picked up card: " + cardid + " from div classname: " + classtext);
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="Lane-Container-2">
      <div class="Lane-Title-2">Urgent Doing</div>
      <div class="Lane-Area-2">
                <div class="Card-Container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" id="11111">
                <div class="Card-Title" style="background-color: black; border-color: black;" onclick="">xxx</div>
                <div class="Card-Body" style="background-color:@i.TypeColorHex; border-color: @i.TypeColorHex;">yyy</div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="Lane-Container-2">
      <div class="Lane-Title-2">2.....Urgent Doing</div>
      <div class="Lane-Area-2">
                <div class="Card-Container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" id="22222">
                <div class="Card-Title" style="background-color: black; border-color: black;" onclick="">xxx</div>
                <div class="Card-Body" style="background-color:@i.TypeColorHex; border-color: @i.TypeColorHex;">yyy</div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(".Card-Container").parents("div").prev().text()` to get the required div text

```js
console.log($(".Card-Container").parents("div").prev().text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Lane-Container-2">
  <div class="Lane-Title-2">Urgent Doing</div>
  <div class="Lane-Area-2">
            <div class="Card-Container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" id="@i.Id">
            <div class="Card-Title" style="background-color: black; border-color: black;" onclick="">xxx</div>
            <div class="Card-Body" style="background-color:@i.TypeColorHex; border-color: @i.TypeColorHex;">yyy</div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, if the Card-Container is the only thing on the page, but unfortunately there is more on the page (please see my revised example)

Comment: you should not have same `ids` on your page.

Comment: Fixed, thanks, they are different inside my Razor foreach loop, but I omitted that part in my example

Comment: as you already mentioned you've got the id. Just replace the class selector with the id selector like `$("#1122").parents("div").prev().text()` and that should work

Comment: interesting, just tried that in my post above, but in my code i get classname=(blank) and in the snippet on SO I get an error about `$`

Comment: Use `$('#'+cardid).parents("div").prev().text()`

Comment: That did the trick, though i did change `parents` to `parent` to just go one div up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170441/discussion-between-george-bailey-and-rilcon42).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
....
ev.dataTransfer.setData("div_from_classname", $(this).parent().className);
....
```

Comment: returns `undefined`

Comment: $(this) might be returning the event but not the element itself. If the ID is returned correctly with ev.target.id, then get the whole child element so that parent would return the whole div.